# How to make a dictionary of arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, dictionary, mapping, containers

I can't seem to figure out how `containers.Map` works. It's doing okay with characters and numbers, but flips out when I try to feed it arrays. How do I make something like this?

```
function test
global a

a = containers.Map();
a(pi) = 3:14;
a(5) = 4:2:10;

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the default constructor for the [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) class. From the help:

> myMap = **containers.Map**() creates an empty object myMap that is an
>       instance of the MATLAB **containers.Map** class. The properties of myMap
>       are Count (set to 0), KeyType (set to 'char'), and ValueType (set to
>       'any').

In other words, you can only use strings as keys in this form. If you want to use arbitrary double precision values as keys, you need to specify the `'KeyType'` and `'ValueType'` in the constructor:

> myMap = **containers.Map**('KeyType', kType, 'ValueType', vType) constructs 
>       a **Map** object with no data that uses a key type of kType, and a value
>       type of vType. Valid values for kType are the strings: 'char',
>       'double', 'single', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', 'uint64'. Valid values
>       for vType are the strings: 'char', 'double', 'single', 'int8', 'uint8',
>       'int16', 'uint16', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', 'uint64', 'logical', or
>       'any'. The order of the key type and value type arguments is not
>       important, but both must be provided.

In your example:

```
a = containers.Map('KeyType','double','ValueType','any');
a(pi) = 3:14;
a(5) = 4:2:10;
```

Note, however, that a `'ValueType'` of `'double'` will not work for non-scalar values. Alternatively, you can specify your keys and values directly with [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) via the constructor and let it do the work of figuring out what types to use:

```
a = containers.Map({pi,5},{3:14 4:2:10});
```

Comment: Yay! Perfect, thank you :] would you mind also answering a follow-up question please? :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407920/non-scalar-in-uniform-output-error-in-arrayfun-how-to-fix

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with putting arrays, cells, even other maps inside a map. The issue is your key field. As far as I know, Maps use strings as keys. So your current code won't work, but this would

```
function test
    global a

    a = containers.Map();
    a('pi') = 3:14;
    a('5') = 4:2:10;

end
```

Comment: containers.Map can use 'char', 'double', 'single', 'int32', 'uint32', 'int64', or 'uint64' as input ... so a number pi should be fine ... i don't think that's the problem ... I think it might be trying to pull "pi"'th element from a, kind of like y(2) would output "2" if y is an array y = 1 2. But I'm not sure how to tell it that a(pi) is an array, not an element of an array